# ARCHIMESH on Blender 3.1 does not appear on Add Mesh Menu

Tags: add-on, archimesh-add-on

I am using Blender 3.1  I am making A building for my model railroad.  Built the walls and needed to make a door and windows I found ARCHIMESH so I downloaded the zip file and placed it in my blender Addon folder on windows.   When I go to Edit preferences I place a check mark for the ARCHIMESH  I save the preferences restart blender 3.1 and when I click on ADD then MESH I do not see ARCHIMESH on the pop out menu,  ARCHIMESH is version 6   I am at a loss on why I do not see this I have added other addons with no issue.  I found several videos on Youtube but no 3.1 Blender and ARCHIMESH
Any ideas or suggestions

Comment: Archimesh is a built-in addon. There's no need to download a zip file to install it! Once enabled, the entry for it shold be right at the bottom of the Add > Mesh menu.

Comment: OK then How do I enable the feature

Comment: You enable it by the method you detailed in your question, but rather than downloading some zip file you just type 'archimesh' into the addon search field of the preferences > addons window and check the entry that search finds. Before you search for that built-in version, I'd be inclined to click the dropdown on the currently installed one on the addon tab and see if there's a 'Remove' button on it. Get rid of that one and then search for and install the correct one which should be version 1.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

It should show up in the Add → Mesh menu.  It now also has its own tab in the sidebar.  To open the Sidebar use the <kbd>N</kbd> shortcut (it's a toogle.) On the sidebar you'll find a tab labeled *Create*. Open that tab and there will be a closed panel for *Archimesh*.  Open it and you'll find:

[image: Archimesh Create panel in sidebar]

Aside: as mentioned in a comment on your question, Archimesh is a built in and you don't have to download or install it; only enable it.  Perhaps you downloaded the wrong version.  Here's a 3.1 add menu snapshot showing archimesh

[image: 3.1 archimesh entry]

Second aside: If you're wondering where to find an add-on, take a look at its entry in the add-ons part of preferences.  There's usually a *Location* entry:

[image: Archimesh add-on preferences entry with location highlighted.]

Comment: Marty  Thanks for the info     I do not have that folder in my Blender folder  I see many other Add Mesh in the addon and many Mesh folder in the addons folder but none named archimesh     is there an update to blender that may put the files there or should I reinstall blender or is there a place where I can get a archimesh addon for 3.1 of blender?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks

Everyone I reran the install of blender 3.1 and did a repair and it copied the files back. When I downloaded the addon and ran the install it overlaid the original files

Now I see Add Mesh ARCHIMESH  on Menu

Thanks again